# Heroku Redis with Django Channels no longer works after removing h username

Tags: heroku, redis, django-channels, heroku-redis

I have been using Heroku Redis to power Django Channels for a while.  My old, existing implementation works.  I tried to set up a new app in the pipeline, but when I provision a new Heroku Redis resource it generates it without a username.  When I try to use that URI to connect Channels it gives me a 104 error.  I can swap the URI with the URI from my old app and it functions, so I'm sure it's the new addon causing the problems.  I've tried resetting the credentials and it did not fix the problem.  I've also tried updating the packages

How do I get Channels to connect using a URI with no username?  Can I force a username?  Can I force an old version of Redis that has the username?